# Pushing S3 data from one AWS account to another S3 bucket using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My use-case is to push data from one AWS account S3 bucket to another AWS account S3 bucket continuously. A cross account push.

I’m using lambda to do this job.

Assume in AWS account A, data is frequently landed from some source into S3 bucket. I need to create an S3 trigger which will invoke Lambda function in AWS account A and push account A S3 bucket data to another S3 bucket in AWS account B.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Firstly, if the buckets are in different regions, you could use Cross-Region Replication and Amazon S3 will do it all for you automatically.

If not, then your proposed plan looks fine. It would involve:

- An **Amazon S3 Event** to trigger the Lambda function whenever a new object is created
- The **Lambda function** receives the Bucket Name and Key of the new object
- The Lambda function should then call `CopyObject()` to **copy the object to the other bucket** (in the other account)

The most important element is to **give permissions to the Lambda function** running in `Account-A` to write to the bucket in `Account-B`. This can be done by:

- Creating an **IAM Role** (`Role-A`) in `Account-A` that is used by the Lambda function
- Adding a **Bucket Policy** to the bucket in `Account-B` that permits `PutObject` from `Role-A` (by specifying the ARN of `Role-A`)

Comment: Appreciate your time and response John. Will try your suggested method and update here